# Trackpad and keyboard no longer work on any linux distribution but work on GRUB / Windows and BIOS menu

Tags: ubuntu, hardware, elementary-os, freeze

I having trouble with my computer.
I have Elementary OS (Ubuntu) / OpenSuse and Windows installed and suddently the trackpad and the keyboard integrated in my laptop stop to work. When I try to reboot, the keyboard work on GRUB and on BIOS menu, and if I choose Windows it's also work with the trackpad, but when I boot on any Linux distribution it's stop working.

I have try to boot in Ubuntu Live, when I have the choice for try or install Ubuntu the keyboard work but just after, in the first screen on the installation the keyboard and the trackpad stop to work.

To finish, when I use external keyboard or mouse with USB it's works and its the only way to use any Linux distribution on my computer now :/

The problem has appear suddently when I was on Elementary OS the keyboard and the trackpad freeze after an suspended activity, I try to reboot and it's appear that the keyboard and the trackpad don't want to work.

I have an HP EliteBook 850 G3

Here is my grub.cfg : http://pastebin.com/VY5y5wS3

The output of uname -a : Linux my-laptop 4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 26 19:39:52 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I use the last Elementary version (Loki) like the screen : http://prnt.sc/d83vdk

Comment: what kernel options are in use on the linux line in `grub.cfg` for the affected installations?

Comment: @ElderGeek Hello, how I can show this file ?

Comment: The file is located in `/boot/grub/` You can open it with your favorite text editor and copy the content and then post it to a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) service and [edit] the link into your post.

Comment: `cat /proc/cmdline`  will show it too.

Comment: Thanks here is my grub.cfg : http://pastebin.com/VY5y5wS3

Comment: Can you show `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | egrep  'key|synapt'`